# Anyone know how to get Sibelius to playback pizzicato at a softer dynamic level without writing the dynamic ridiculously soft?

Tags: strings, sibelius, pizzicato

Sibelius playback of pizzicato is much louder than arco for strings. I end up making two copies of a score. One with the dynamics as they should be written for pizzicato for printing and another copy with the pizzicato sections being written at pp or ppp to not over balance any Arco instruments. Is there a global setting that can make pizzicato more realistic dynamically?

Comment: How is the sound created? Are you using the sounds straight from sibelius, or an external MIDI sound font? Are you notating the pizz in "technic text" (CMD + T) ?

Comment: idk Sibelius [haven't used it in 20 years] but check if it reads & writes ctrl 7 &/or ctrl 11 data

Answer (score 1):

- Play|Instrument Changes|New Instrument Change
- select the instrument(s) and adjust the volume